# Image gets drawn below Polygon

Tags: java, graphics

For a Project I need to code a simple 2D Game, where a Plane has to defend a city against falling bombs. First I created the Polygon of all the Game Objects in order to have a "hitbox" and now I wanted to place the actual Sprites over it. The Problem here now is that the picture gets drawn directly under the Polygon and not on it how its supposed to do and it's driving me crazy.

**Player Class**

```
 public class Player extends GameObject {

private GameState gameState = new GameState();


public Player ()
{
    this.active=true;
    this.gameRelevant=true;

    this.height=game.GameSettings.playerHeight;
    this.width = game.GameSettings.playerWidth;
    this.color=Color.BLACK;

    this.position= new Point2D.Double(game.GameSettings.gamePanelWidth/2,game.GameSettings.gamePanelHeight/2);
    this.damage=0;
    this.polygon = game.GameController.BuildingType.getShape(game.GameSettings.playerPolygonXValues, game.GameSettings.playerPolygonYValues);
    this.img = io.ImageLoader.getPlayerLookingToRightImage(this.width, this.height);
}
    public void draw (Graphics2D g)
{
    AffineTransform spieler = new AffineTransform();
    spieler.translate(this.position.x, this.position.y);
    Shape s = spieler.createTransformedShape(this.polygon);

    g.setColor(this.color);
    g.fill(s);
    g.drawImage(img,spieler,null);



    g.draw(s);



}
```

**The GetShape Method for creating Polygons**

```
    public static Polygon getShape (double[] varx, double[] vary)
    {   
        Polygon hitbox= new Polygon();


                if(varx == GameSettings.churchPolygonXValues)       
                {
                    for(int j=0; j<GameSettings.churchPolygonXValues.length;j++)
                    {
                        hitbox.addPoint((int)(varx[j]*GameSettings.churchWidth), (int)(vary[j]*GameSettings.churchHeight));
                    }

                }


                if(varx == GameSettings.houseBluePolygonXValues)
                {   
                    for(int j=0; j<GameSettings.houseBluePolygonXValues.length;j++)
                    {
                        hitbox.addPoint((int)(varx[j]*GameSettings.houseBlueWidth), (int)(vary[j]*GameSettings.houseBlueHeight));
                    }
                }

                if(varx == GameSettings.houseRedPolygonXValues)
                {
                    for(int j=0; j<GameSettings.houseRedPolygonXValues.length;j++)
                    {
                        hitbox.addPoint((int)(varx[j]*GameSettings.houseRedWidth), (int)(vary[j]*GameSettings.houseRedHeight));
                    }

                }

                if(varx == GameSettings.houseYellowPolygonXValues)
                {
                    for(int j=0; j<GameSettings.houseYellowPolygonXValues.length;j++)
                    {
                        hitbox.addPoint((int)(varx[j]*GameSettings.houseYellowWidth), (int)(vary[j]*GameSettings.houseYellowHeight));
                    }

                }

                if(varx == GameSettings.playerPolygonXValues)
                {
                    for(int j=0; j<GameSettings.playerPolygonXValues.length;j++)
                    {
                        hitbox.addPoint((int)(varx[j]*GameSettings.playerWidth), (int)(vary[j]*GameSettings.playerHeight));
                    }

                }


        return hitbox;
    }
}
```

**Running the Game**
[image]

All the other variables like Panel Width and Height or the Images are given as Project Instructions and thus they can't be wrong. If you need anymore Information, just tell me. Does anyone have an Idea?